# ConfigurationManager.AppSettings won't read new/updated settings

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2022

I have a console app built on `.NET Framework 4.7.2` and I'm using `VS2022`. I have been using both `<appSettings>` in `App.config` and `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["xxx"]` for many years with no problems ever.

Until 1 week ago. In this simple console app I'm finding that any setting that is new won't be read until...some future time. Maybe tomorrow or the next day? Maybe after a reboot? The new setting value keeps coming back as `null` even though the other settings are read just fine. Here is the latest example:

```
<appSettings>
   <add key="DataFilePath" value="D:\some\place" />
   ... several more key/value pairs here ...
</appSettings>
```

I just added the `DataFilePath` setting today and my console app comes back `null` when I read it thusly:

```
ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DataFilePath"]
```

WTH??

All those other settings I have get read just fine.

Additionally: When I change the `value` portion of a setting, my console app will keep seeing the old value all day...until tomorrow...reboot...etc. (Not sure what.)

I did a bunch of google searches and was directed to delete the hidden `.vs` folder in the solution root. That seemed to solve it for updated values being read as the old values...but does nothing to enable a brand new setting (such as `DataFilePath` shown above) to be read.

I stop and re-start the console app frequently. It's not as though it just runs continuously and I change values while it's running and not restart it. No.

I could understand a problem like this happening in ASP.NET, maybe with IIS caching something, etc. But this is a simple console app and there is no caching going on at all. Furthermore, I have been using .NET Framework 4.7.2 for at least a few years and have never seen a problem like this before.

This is a brand new console app that I built from scratch. I didn't inherit it, there's not the possibility of a ton of code someplace in some others parts of the app that might be interfering. I have stepped through the code and confirmed this behavior.

I have seen posts about strange config behaviors in .NET Core - but this is not that. It's plain old .NET Framework.

What is going on??

Comment: If I understand it correctly, you have an application in Visual Studio which you are debugging, and changing/adding an appSettings value in your config doesn't (always) propagate. What are the steps to repro this? Do you rebuild? Publish? Hit F5? You do realize you have an app.config in source, and a copy in the output directory?

Comment: As another commenter stated, in Visual Studio Solution Explorer one can see `App.config`. When one builds (Build => Build Solution; Build => Rebuild Solution), it creates `<ApplicationName>.exe.config` which one can see in the output folder (ie: `bin\Debug`) which is used during execution. Which file you made the modifications in is unclear.

Comment: Your questions led me to the solution: It turns out that in the App.config properties, the `Copy to Output Directory` property was set to `Do not copy`. Frick. Changing that solved everything. At this point I'm baffled how it EVER worked. The xxx.exe.config file was there and only had yesterday's settings. Why would that have even been there? I guess it decided on its own to copy it sometimes. Anyway THANK YOU CodeCaster and user09938 for pointing me in the right direction. I did not set the property that way and never saw it default that way in the past.

Comment: The following may be of interest: [Application Settings Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2010/k4s6c3a0(v=vs.100)), [Application Settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2010/a65txexh(v=vs.100)?redirectedfrom=MSDN), [Application Settings Architecture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2010/8eyb2ct1(v=vs.100)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)